# What's the means of variable >> variable in c++?

Tags: c++

I want to known a simple thing. I have this part of code:

```
int datam=2;
for (int j=0; j<4; j++){
  cout<<((datam >> j)&1); 
}
```

What does it print this code? Does it do the AND bit to bit between `1` and `datam>>j`? As operator, what's the meaning of `datam >> j`? Thanks.

Comment: Have you read the [manual](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_arithmetic) first?

Comment: Valid question, even in software engineering classes they say that `>>` is stream operator not even mentioning about bit shifts.
It does not mean however that google wouldn't know.

Comment: @riodoro1 Have you ever tried searching for punctuation? Try typing `>>` into Google.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- When passed two `int` operants, `&` is the bitwise AND operator.
- When passed two `int` operands, `>>` is the bitwise right shift operator.

You can learn more details from any good text book, or online reference. For instance: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_arithmetic